# Unable to get updated value of customfield using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jira, jira-plugin

I have added below javascript on textbox custom field's description.

```
setInterval(function(){console.log('value   is:'+AJS.$("#customfield_11426\\:input1").val());  //unable to get updated value on each    interval tick, it just prints initial value which is found while loading edit issue screen.
},2000);
```

It executes on 2 sec but it just print same value of input1 textbox instead of updated values.

(just take the value which is found while loading issue edit screen but unable to get updated textbox values).

I need these updated value for further calculation.

Can you tell me what can be the cause and how to resolve .

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HVGnC/1/

Comment: actually, this occurs on JIRA - issue edit screen where i have used this custom field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You guys for your comments.

actually, in JIRA edit screen, i did not get updated value of textbox through AJS.$("#controlid").val() and it just give me same value which was on load time.
Even in firebug inspect element shows old value which was on load time and did not show me updated value. so setInterval works but just write old value.

But it can resolve through "change" event as below:

```
 AJS.$('#customfield_11426\\:input1').bind('change', function (e) {
   console.log("value of input1" + AJS.$(this).val());   //this object only correct value.
 });
```

Thank You
Dhaval Soni